# What does Linux accent-grave command do?

Tags: linux, bash

In a bash shell (A), typing an <kbd>`</kbd> (accent-grave) will start another shell prompt (B). The output of any command entered in B is a command for A.

```
$ `
> whoami`
-bash: Joe: command not found
```

(If my username were Joe.)

```
$ man `
> `
What manual page do you want?
```

Is there a man page for this, preferably with some examples?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is in the bash manual. Search for `backquote` (substitution)

```
When  the  old-style  backquote form of substitution is used, backslash
retains its literal meaning except when followed by $, `,  or  \.   The
first backquote not preceded by a backslash terminates the command sub‐
stitution.  When using the $(command) form, all characters between  the
parentheses make up the command; none are treated specially.

Command substitutions may be nested.  To nest when using the backquoted
form, escape the inner backquotes with backslashes.
```

I find `$()` easier to use, especially when nesting things.

Comment: [also worth a mention](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xcu_chap02.html#tag_23_02_06_03)